# Timer/thread colaescing

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, trading, timer-jobs

I have a small project which needs to track stock price % movement for specified time intervals. E.g. It should be able to track AAPL price % move for the last 30sec, 1min, 3min, 5min, 10min. All stocks share the same time intervals. Program will be written in C++ and will be running on Linux, though it shouldn't matter.

Below is the approach I am thinking of,

1) Get stock market data from multicast feed, for around 4000 symbols

2) Process the feed and store them in a global quotes cache

3) Spawn N number of threads, one for each interval

4) Each thread will maintain its own copy of symbols, on startup initialize each symbol with current price from the global cache, then go to sleep for specified interval

5) On wake up, snap the current price (from the quote cache which would have the latest value from the quotes feed), calculate the difference, push this information to a queue

6) Have a dedicated thread to read the queue and publish the prices to a caching server

7) Front end GUI applications read from the caching server and display the percent moves

This approach should work, but is there a better way to do this? Also one area of optimization could be coalescing the thread price snapping part(after the thread wakes up), where if two or more threads will be snapping at the same time, e.g. the 30sec, 1min and 2min threads will snap together every two minutes, so combine them into one snap. What logic can I use to do the coalescing? Thank you.

Comment: You can do this with one thread and a timer chain. Each stock goes into a priority queue sorted by the next time a quote is required. The program goes to sleep, waking up at the first time in the queue. This stock and all stocks expiring at the same time read and display, then get replaced in the queue at their next display time. The program then goes back to sleep until the first time in the queue. No synch problems this way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So I have to maintain one object(with symbol, expiry, price) per symbol per interval in the queue. And thread constantly reads the queue and sees if the time is up for each object, if so calculate diff and publish. Then recreate/reuse the object, update the price and expiry and put it back in the queue. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Close. You don't have to constantly read the queue. Just set a timer for when the first item in the queue is going to expire, sleep until the timer goes off, then read and re-propritize until the time changes. Then set a timer for the new time and go back to sleep.

Comment: That's a nice approach, thanks a lot. Hopefully after implementation I'll post the full solution.